# Chef Error : Invalid or missing manifest .json, .rb, or .yml file provided

Tags: ruby, json, amazon-web-services, chef-recipe

I am very new to chef. I am trying to launch aws instance using chef getting following error.

[root@PROD-CHEF-CLIENT chef]# chef exec spiceweasel -T 2600 -e

```
cookbooks/delivery-server-setup/server_create.rb

==========================================
**Selected Organization::development**
==========================================

ERROR: Invalid or missing  manifest .json, .rb, or .yml file provided.
[root@APROD-CHEF-CLIENT chef]#
```

cat cookbooks/delivery-server-setup/server_create.rb

```
{
        'cookbooks'     =>
        [
                {'common' => {}},
                {"hostsfile" => {}},
                {"s3cmd-master" => {}},
                {"delivery-server-setup" => {}}
        ],
        'nodes' =>
        [
{'ec2 1' =>
   {
    'run_list' => 'recipe[-delivery-server-setup::install]',
    'options'  => "-S -keypair -I ami-fb5d7f91 --user-data /mnt/chef/delivery_user_data -Z us-east-1c --groups -delivery -f c3.4xlarge --ssh-user auto_deploy -i /home/auto_deploy/.ssh/id_rsa --tags \"Name=-PROD-DEL-DB51-C-71\" --node-name \"-PROD-DEL-DB51-C-71\""
   }
  }

{'ec2 1' =>
   {
    'run_list' => 'recipe[-delivery-server-setup::install]',
    'options'  => "-S -keypair -I ami-fb5d7f91 --user-data /mnt/chef/delivery_user_data -Z us-east-1c --groups -delivery -f c3.4xlarge --ssh-user auto_deploy -i /home/auto_deploy/.ssh/id_rsa --tags \"Name=-PROD-DEL-DB52-C-72\" --node-name \"-PROD-DEL-DB52-C-72\""
   }
  }

{'ec2 1' =>
   {
    'run_list' => 'recipe[-delivery-server-setup::install]',
    'options'  => "-S -keypair -I ami-fb5d7f91 --user-data /mnt/chef/delivery_user_data -Z us-east-1c --groups -delivery -f c3.4xlarge --ssh-user auto_deploy -i /home/auto_deploy/.ssh/id_rsa --tags \"Name=-PROD-DEL-DB52-C-73\" --node-name \"-PROD-DEL-DB52-C-73\""
   }
  }

{'ec2 1' =>
   {
    'run_list' => 'recipe[-delivery-server-setup::install]',
    'options'  => "-S -keypair -I ami-fb5d7f91 --user-data /mnt/chef/delivery_user_data -Z us-east-1c --groups -delivery -f c3.4xlarge --ssh-user auto_deploy -i /home/auto_deploy/.ssh/id_rsa --tags \"Name=-PROD-DEL-DB52-C-74\" --node-name \"-PROD-DEL-DB52-C-74\""
   }
  }

{'ec2 1' =>
   {
    'run_list' => 'recipe[-delivery-server-setup::install]',
    'options'  => "-S -keypair -I ami-fb5d7f91 --user-data /mnt/chef/delivery_user_data -Z us-east-1c --groups -delivery -f c3.4xlarge --ssh-user auto_deploy -i /home/auto_deploy/.ssh/id_rsa --tags \"Name=-PROD-DEL-DB52-C-75\" --node-name \"-PROD-DEL-DB52-C-75\""
   }
  }



{'ec2 1' =>
   {
    'run_list' => 'recipe[-delivery-server-setup::install]',
    'options'  => "-S -keypair -I ami-fb5d7f91 --user-data /mnt/chef/delivery_user_data -Z us-east-1d --groups -delivery -f c3.4xlarge --ssh-user auto_deploy -i /home/auto_deploy/.ssh/id_rsa --tags \"Name=-PROD-DEL-DB06-D-71\" --node-name \"-PROD-DEL-DB06-D-71\""
   }
  }

{'ec2 1' =>
   {
    'run_list' => 'recipe[-delivery-server-setup::install]',
    'options'  => "-S -keypair -I ami-fb5d7f91 --user-data /mnt/chef/delivery_user_data -Z us-east-1d --groups -delivery -f c3.4xlarge --ssh-user auto_deploy -i /home/auto_deploy/.ssh/id_rsa --tags \"Name=-PROD-DEL-DB06-D-72\" --node-name \"-PROD-DEL-DB06-D-72\""
   }
  }

{'ec2 1' =>
   {
    'run_list' => 'recipe[-delivery-server-setup::install]',
    'options'  => "-S -keypair -I ami-fb5d7f91 --user-data /mnt/chef/delivery_user_data -Z us-east-1d --groups -delivery -f c3.4xlarge --ssh-user auto_deploy -i /home/auto_deploy/.ssh/id_rsa --tags \"Name=-PROD-DEL-DB06-D-73\" --node-name \"-PROD-DEL-DB06-D-73\""
   }
  }

{'ec2 1' =>
   {
    'run_list' => 'recipe[-delivery-server-setup::install]',
    'options'  => "-S -keypair -I ami-fb5d7f91 --user-data /mnt/chef/delivery_user_data -Z us-east-1d --groups -delivery -f c3.4xlarge --ssh-user auto_deploy -i /home/auto_deploy/.ssh/id_rsa --tags \"Name=-PROD-DEL-DB06-D-74\" --node-name \"-PROD-DEL-DB06-D-74\""
   }
  }

{'ec2 1' =>
   {
    'run_list' => 'recipe[-delivery-server-setup::install]',
    'options'  => "-S -keypair -I ami-fb5d7f91 --user-data /mnt/chef/delivery_user_data -Z us-east-1d --groups -delivery -f c3.4xlarge --ssh-user auto_deploy -i /home/auto_deploy/.ssh/id_rsa --tags \"Name=-PROD-DEL-DB06-D-75\" --node-name \"-PROD-DEL-DB06-D-75\""
   }
  }

]

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're not passing a well-formed config file, which spiceweasel is expecting (usually something along the lines of `infrastructure.yml`, but it can also be a .rb).

The file you've copy-pasted has a few syntax errors. Basically, you're missing a ',' between the `nodes` array elements.

Here's the corrected version:

```
{
  'cookbooks' =>
    [
      { 'common' => {} },
      { 'hostsfile' => {} },
      { 's3cmd-master' => {} },
      { 'delivery-server-setup' => {} }
    ],
  'nodes' =>
    [
      { 'ec2 1' =>
         {
           'run_list' => 'recipe[-delivery-server-setup::install]',
           'options'  => "-S -keypair -I ami-fb5d7f91 --user-data /mnt/chef/delivery_user_data -Z us-east-1c --groups -delivery -f c3.4xlarge --ssh-user auto_deploy -i /home/auto_deploy/.ssh/id_rsa --tags \"Name=-PROD-DEL-DB51-C-71\" --node-name \"-PROD-DEL-DB51-C-71\""
         }
      },
      { 'ec2 1' =>
         {
           'run_list' => 'recipe[-delivery-server-setup::install]',
           'options'  => "-S -keypair -I ami-fb5d7f91 --user-data /mnt/chef/delivery_user_data -Z us-east-1c --groups -delivery -f c3.4xlarge --ssh-user auto_deploy -i /home/auto_deploy/.ssh/id_rsa --tags \"Name=-PROD-DEL-DB52-C-72\" --node-name \"-PROD-DEL-DB52-C-72\""
         }
      },
      { 'ec2 1' =>
         {
           'run_list' => 'recipe[-delivery-server-setup::install]',
           'options'  => "-S -keypair -I ami-fb5d7f91 --user-data /mnt/chef/delivery_user_data -Z us-east-1c --groups -delivery -f c3.4xlarge --ssh-user auto_deploy -i /home/auto_deploy/.ssh/id_rsa --tags \"Name=-PROD-DEL-DB52-C-73\" --node-name \"-PROD-DEL-DB52-C-73\""
         }
      },
      { 'ec2 1' =>
         {
           'run_list' => 'recipe[-delivery-server-setup::install]',
           'options'  => "-S -keypair -I ami-fb5d7f91 --user-data /mnt/chef/delivery_user_data -Z us-east-1c --groups -delivery -f c3.4xlarge --ssh-user auto_deploy -i /home/auto_deploy/.ssh/id_rsa --tags \"Name=-PROD-DEL-DB52-C-74\" --node-name \"-PROD-DEL-DB52-C-74\""
         }
      },
      { 'ec2 1' =>
         {
           'run_list' => 'recipe[-delivery-server-setup::install]',
           'options'  => "-S -keypair -I ami-fb5d7f91 --user-data /mnt/chef/delivery_user_data -Z us-east-1c --groups -delivery -f c3.4xlarge --ssh-user auto_deploy -i /home/auto_deploy/.ssh/id_rsa --tags \"Name=-PROD-DEL-DB52-C-75\" --node-name \"-PROD-DEL-DB52-C-75\""
         }
      },
      { 'ec2 1' =>
         {
           'run_list' => 'recipe[-delivery-server-setup::install]',
           'options'  => "-S -keypair -I ami-fb5d7f91 --user-data /mnt/chef/delivery_user_data -Z us-east-1d --groups -delivery -f c3.4xlarge --ssh-user auto_deploy -i /home/auto_deploy/.ssh/id_rsa --tags \"Name=-PROD-DEL-DB06-D-71\" --node-name \"-PROD-DEL-DB06-D-71\""
         }
      },

      { 'ec2 1' =>
         {
           'run_list' => 'recipe[-delivery-server-setup::install]',
           'options'  => "-S -keypair -I ami-fb5d7f91 --user-data /mnt/chef/delivery_user_data -Z us-east-1d --groups -delivery -f c3.4xlarge --ssh-user auto_deploy -i /home/auto_deploy/.ssh/id_rsa --tags \"Name=-PROD-DEL-DB06-D-72\" --node-name \"-PROD-DEL-DB06-D-72\""
         }
      },

      { 'ec2 1' =>
         {
           'run_list' => 'recipe[-delivery-server-setup::install]',
           'options'  => "-S -keypair -I ami-fb5d7f91 --user-data /mnt/chef/delivery_user_data -Z us-east-1d --groups -delivery -f c3.4xlarge --ssh-user auto_deploy -i /home/auto_deploy/.ssh/id_rsa --tags \"Name=-PROD-DEL-DB06-D-73\" --node-name \"-PROD-DEL-DB06-D-73\""
         }
      },

      { 'ec2 1' =>
         {
           'run_list' => 'recipe[-delivery-server-setup::install]',
           'options'  => "-S -keypair -I ami-fb5d7f91 --user-data /mnt/chef/delivery_user_data -Z us-east-1d --groups -delivery -f c3.4xlarge --ssh-user auto_deploy -i /home/auto_deploy/.ssh/id_rsa --tags \"Name=-PROD-DEL-DB06-D-74\" --node-name \"-PROD-DEL-DB06-D-74\""
         }
      },

      { 'ec2 1' =>
         {
           'run_list' => 'recipe[-delivery-server-setup::install]',
           'options'  => "-S -keypair -I ami-fb5d7f91 --user-data /mnt/chef/delivery_user_data -Z us-east-1d --groups -delivery -f c3.4xlarge --ssh-user auto_deploy -i /home/auto_deploy/.ssh/id_rsa --tags \"Name=-PROD-DEL-DB06-D-75\" --node-name \"-PROD-DEL-DB06-D-75\""
         }
      }
    ]
}
```

That should solve this problem.